# Problem with my search and copy script with filtered cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a script in google sheets, that searches after a button click in 2 separat sheets for the same cell entry within column 3 (C). If it finds the a match, it should copy column 1,2, 8,9 from sheet2 to the matched row of sheet1.

My sheet has got 1000+ rows and my script timeouted with the script. I am not very good at coding, maybe there is more optimazation possible, but my idea is to first apply filter in each sheet, so that there a loooot less rows left. (for now manually applied filters)

With my script I get an error: "TypeError: sheet1.getFilter(...).getRange(...).getFilteredRows is not a function". I dont know how to fix this.

It is my idea to shorten the script with this filter method, so that the script does not need to search in 1000+ rows for 2 sheets.

I hope anyone can help me and can tell me what the error is about.

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  // Iterate through all rows in sheet1 and set the height to 42 pixels
  for (var i = 2; i <= sheet1.getLastRow(); i++) {
    sheet1.setRowHeight(i, 42);
  }

  // Get the visible rows in sheet1
  var visibleRowsSheet1 = sheet1.getFilter().getRange().getFilteredRows();
  // Get data from visible rows in sheet1
  var data1 = sheet1.getRange(1, 3, visibleRowsSheet1.length, 1).getValues();

  // Get the visible rows in sheet2
  var visibleRowsSheet2 = sheet2.getFilter().getRange().getFilteredRows();
  // Get data from visible rows in sheet2
  var data2 = sheet2.getRange(1, 3, visibleRowsSheet2.length, 1).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
    var entryToSearch = data1[i][0];

    for (var j = 0; j < data2.length; j++) {
      if (entryToSearch === data2[j][0]) {
        // If there is a match, copy columns 1, 2, 7, and 8 from sheet2 to sheet1
        var valuesToCopy12 = sheet2.getRange(visibleRowsSheet2[j], 1, 1, 2).getValues();
        sheet1.getRange(visibleRowsSheet1[i], 1, 1, 2).setValues(valuesToCopy12);
        var valuesToCopy78 = sheet2.getRange(visibleRowsSheet2[j], 7, 1, 2).getValues();
        sheet1.getRange(visibleRowsSheet1[i], 7, 1, 2).setValues(valuesToCopy78);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I think that there is no method of `getFilteredRows()` in Class Range. I guess that this might be the reason for your current issue of `TypeError: sheet1.getFilter(...).getRange(...).getFilteredRows is not a function`.
- In your showing script, `getValues` and `setValues` are used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. [Ref (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- I think that in your situation, it is not required to use the basic filter.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

From your showing script and question, I believe that you want to achieve the following result.

- Your Spreadsheet has 2 sheets of "Sheet1" and "Sheet2".
- You want to compare the values of column "C" of both "Sheet1" and "Sheet2".
- When the same values are found, you want to copy the values of columns "A" and "B" of "Sheet2" to columns "A" and "B", and want to copy the values of columns "H" and "I" to columns "G" and "H", respectively.

  - In your question, you say `If it finds the a match, it should copy column 1,2, 8,9 from sheet2 to the matched row of sheet1.`. But, in your script, you say `If there is a match, copy columns 1, 2, 7, and 8 from sheet2 to sheet1`. I couldn't understand what you want to do. So, in this answer, I would like to respect `If it finds the a match, it should copy column 1,2, 8,9 from sheet2 to the matched row of sheet1.`. Please be careful about this.

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var range1 = sheet1.getDataRange();
  var values1 = range1.getValues();
  var values2 = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();
  var obj1 = new Map(values2.map(r => [r[2], [[r[0], r[1]], [r[7], r[8]]]]));
  var change = false;
  var newValues2 = values1.map(r => {
    if (obj1.has(r[2])) {
      change = true;
      const [a, b] = obj1.get(r[2]);
      return [...a, ...r.slice(2, 6), ...b, ...r.slice(8)];
    }
    return r;
  });
  if (!change) return;
  range1.setValues(newValues2);
}
```

- When this script is run, when the values of column "C" of "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" are the same, the values of columns "A" and "B" and the values of columns "H" and "I" are copied to columns "A", "B" and "G", "H", respectively.
- In this modification, I used `If it finds the a match, it should copy column 1,2, 8,9 from sheet2 to the matched row of sheet1.`. If you want `If there is a match, copy columns 1, 2, 7, and 8 from sheet2 to sheet1`, please modify `var obj1 = new Map(values2.map(r => [r[2], [[r[0], r[1]], [r[7], r[8]]]]));` to `var obj1 = new Map(values2.map(r => [r[2], [[r[0], r[1]], [r[6], r[7]]]]));`.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> Ah so I find in your answer the problem Here, the Map object is created. This is from your showing script. The values of columns "A" and "B" and the values of columns "H" and "I" of "Sheet2" are copied to columns "A", "B" and "G", "H" of "Sheet1", respectively The data from sheet2 should be copied to the same columns in sheet1 so it should copied to columns "A", "B" and "H", "I". This should fix my problem.

In your showing script, it seems that you wanted to achieve that the values of columns "A" and "B" and the values of columns "H" and "I" of "Sheet2" are copied to columns "A", "B" and "G", "H" of "Sheet1", respectively. In this case, how about the following sample script?

In this sample script, when column "C" of "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" are the same, columns "A" and "B", "H" and "I" of those rows of "Sheet2" are copied to columns "A" and "B", "H" and "I" of "Sheet1".

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var range1 = sheet1.getDataRange();
  var values1 = range1.getValues();
  var values2 = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();
  var obj1 = new Map(values2.map(r => [r[2], [[r[0], r[1]], [r[7], r[8]]]]));
  var change = false;
  var newValues2 = values1.map(r => {
    if (obj1.has(r[2])) {
      change = true;
      const [a, b] = obj1.get(r[2]);
      return [...a, ...r.slice(2, 7), ...b, ...r.slice(9)];
    }
    return r;
  });
  if (!change) return;
  range1.setValues(newValues2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped for my small test table. But I dont know if that script works for the 1000+ row table too now (your last solution was my searched one)

How this code works? Is it searching in all rows (no matter if some of them are filtered out) or is it just searching through th visible rows?

I added a script before this search script which intention is to filter all the not needed rows out by values and dates. But I got some problem there too and will open another threa for this.

Comment: @Friedolien Thank you for replying. About `But I dont know if that script works for the 1000+ row table too now (your last solution was my searched one) How this code works?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot correctly imagine your actual Spreadsheet from your question. So, can you test my script with your actual spreadsheet? If my sample script was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Friedolien About `I added a script before this search script which intention is to filter all the not needed rows out by values and dates. But I got some problem there too and will open another threa for this.`, I understood that you will post a new question as another question. By the way, I cannot notice `dates` of `values and dates` from your question. Can I ask you about the detail of it? Because if the compared value is a date object, it is required to modify my script.

Comment: @Friedolien I saw [your new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77765213). In this case, what will you do this question?

Comment: **So, can you test my script with your actual spreadsheet? If my sample script was not useful, I apologize**, I need to test your code in my big table, too,, as I just tested it in my small test table, which worked.

Comment: @Friedolien Thank you for replying. About `I need to test your code in my big table, too,, as I just tested it in my small test table, which worked.`, I understood that my sample script worked in a small table. When you test my script to a big table and that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: No I just needed some time for checking it in my bigger table, so I did. It worked. But I guess column I isnt working properly. Can you have a look on it again. And I missed that I need to add another column after column 3. so H and I needs to bei copied too sheet1 from sheet2 when there is a match. Dont get how to change your code.

So in summary again. Column C needs to be searched for a match in sheet1 and sheet2. If there is a match, the script should copy column A,B and H,I of this match row from sheet2 to the same columns in sheet1. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Friedolien Thank you for replying. From `No I just needed some time for checking it in my bigger table, so I did. It worked.`, I understood that my script works for your actual Spreadsheet. About `But I guess column I isnt working properly. Can you have a look on it again.`, I understood that at least, your question is different from your actual question.

Comment: @Friedolien But, about `Column C needs to be searched for a match in sheet1 and sheet2. If there is a match, the script should copy column A,B and H,I of this match row from sheet2 to the same columns in sheet1`, I think that my sample script has already achieved this. So, I cannot understand your actual question. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the details of your actual question? If you can cooperate to resolve your actual question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Friedolien Can you cooperate to resolve your actual expected result?

Comment: Tanaike sorry for my late answer.

I tried it again. But the copiing of column 9 (I) is not working. The script does not copy the data from sheet2 to sheet1. 
I just edit this code ' var obj1 = new Map(values2.map(r => [r[2], [[r[0], r[1]], [r[6], r[7]]]]));'

Can you explain the code to me? what is "r" and the following numbers? Could you pls modify the script, so that is starts with the search and copy with row 2, because my row 1 is just the cell headlines, which are the same for each sheet. Hope you understand me.

Comment: when I use [7] and [8] the script copies the correct columns from sheet2 but paste it to column 7(G) and 8 (H) instead of 8(H) and 9(I). Thats my only problem left now

Comment: @Friedolien Thank you for replying. About `The script does not copy the data from sheet2 to sheet1.`, in this case, it is required to test your situation using my script. Because, when I tested my script using a sample spreadsheet, the values were copied correctly. I deeply apologize for this situation. But, I would like to confirm it. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current situation as I have already suggested? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your actual question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Friedolien About `I just edit this code 'var obj1 = new Map(values2.map(r => [r[2], [[r[0], r[1]], [r[6], r[7]]]]));' Can you explain the code to me?`, you can see the document of Map object and map function in my answer. Here, the Map object is created. This is from your showing script. The values of columns "A" and "B" and the values of columns "H" and "I" of "Sheet2" are copied to columns "A", "B" and "G", "H" of "Sheet1", respectively.

Comment: @Friedolien But, it seems that from your previous reply, your showing script is different from your actual situation. So, I asked about the details of your actual situation. When I could correctly understand your actual situation and your expected result, I can modify my answer. I deeply apologize that I cannot correctly understand your actual situation soon because of my poor English skill.

Comment: Ah so I find in your answer the problem **Here, the Map object is created. This is from your showing script. The values of columns "A" and "B" and the values of columns "H" and "I" of "Sheet2" are copied to columns "A", "B" and "G", "H" of "Sheet1", respectively**
The data from sheet2 should be copied to the same columns in sheet1 so it should copied to columns "A", "B" and "H", "I". This should fix my problem.

Comment: r[6], r[7] or r[7], r[8] does not fix this

Comment: @Friedolien Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that your actual expected result was that when column "C" of "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" are the same, columns "A" and "B", "H" and "I" of those rows of "Sheet2" are copied to columns "A" and "B", "H" and "I" of "Sheet1". For this, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: Hello @tanaike, I tested the modified script code and it worked like a sharm. Just awesome. Thank you so much, it helped me so much!

Comment: @Friedolien Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.

Comment: Hello again

I need to modify the script a bit: I dont need column H anymore, what do I need to change in your script. I dont understand the code. Thank you!

Comment: @Friedolien About your new question of `Hello again I need to modify the script a bit: I dont need column H anymore, what do I need to change in your script. I dont understand the code. Thank you!`, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Its to much for a new question I guess. I simple dont need the column H to be copied to sheet 1. So your code is the same, but without column H. What do I need to change?

Comment: @Friedolien Thank you for replying. About `Its to much for a new question I guess.`, you cannot post your new question. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, your question has already been resolved. But, you request me to modify my script by a new question. If I answered your new question, you might continue to request other updates in the future. I am afraid of it. So, I recommended posting your new question as a new question. If you can understand this, I'm glad. Can you understand it? If you can do it, I would like to continue to support you.

Comment: @Friedolien Also, I think that the modification point for resolving your new question will be useful for other users. So, if you can post it as a new question, it will be useful for other users. If you can understand it, I'm glad.

Answer (score 0):

Tanaike is correct. The method getFilteredRows() is not a valid method for the Range class. This method only works for the Filter class.

Try changing the way you get the visible rows in each sheet. Instead of using getRange().getFilteredRows(), you can use getRange().getHiddenValues() to get an array of boolean values indicating which rows are hidden by the filter. Then you can loop through this array and only process the rows that are not hidden.

Try this formula:

```
    function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  // Iterate through all rows in sheet1 and set the height to 42 pixels
  for (var i = 2; i <= sheet1.getLastRow(); i++) {
    sheet1.setRowHeight(i, 42);
  }

  // Get the range of data in sheet1
  var range1 = sheet1.getRange(1, 3, sheet1.getLastRow(), 1);
  // Get the values from the range
  var data1 = range1.getValues();
  // Get the hidden values from the range
  var hidden1 = range1.getHiddenValues();

  // Get the range of data in sheet2
  var range2 = sheet2.getRange(1, 3, sheet2.getLastRow(), 1);
  // Get the values from the range
  var data2 = range2.getValues();
  // Get the hidden values from the range
  var hidden2 = range2.getHiddenValues();

  // Loop through the data in sheet1
  for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
    // Skip the hidden rows
    if (hidden1[i][0]) continue;
    var entryToSearch = data1[i][0];

    // Loop through the data in sheet2
    for (var j = 0; j < data2.length; j++) {
      // Skip the hidden rows
      if (hidden2[j][0]) continue;
      if (entryToSearch === data2[j][0]) {
        // If there is a match, copy columns 1, 2, 7, and 8 from sheet2 to sheet1
        var valuesToCopy12 = sheet2.getRange(j + 1, 1, 1, 2).getValues();
        sheet1.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, 2).setValues(valuesToCopy12);
        var valuesToCopy78 = sheet2.getRange(j + 1, 7, 1, 2).getValues();
        sheet1.getRange(i + 1, 7, 1, 2).setValues(valuesToCopy78);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

}
```