# Google Script for applying filters to tables

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a script which deals with sheet1 after clicking a button.
It can be divided in some minor steps.

1. filter column 6 from values 2500 to 2599 (this range should be the only visble in sheet1.
2. Sort column 15 from old date to new date
3. filter column 15 for the last 3 months and next 3 months
4. filter out entries in column 5 with "Minor W", so that there isnt any Minor W text anymore

My problem is, that my code for 1. and 3. isnt working properly and I have no idea why.

The sorting and filtering out "Minor W" is working fine, but not Nr. 1. and 3.
Note that row one are the headlines of the table, the filled cells are starting from row 2. Hope anyone can have a look on this filter script.

Thank you so much

```
function filtered() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet2'); // Replace 'YourSheetName' with your actual sheet name

  // Check if filters are applied to all columns with cell values, and apply if not
  if (!sheet.getDataRange().getFilter()) {
  sheet.getDataRange().createFilter();
  }

   Filter column 6 from values 2500 to 2599
  sheet.getFilter().getRange().createFilter();
  sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(6, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(['', '<2500', '>2599']).build());
  
  // Sort column 15 from old date to new date 
  sheet.getRange(2, 15, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).sort({ column: 15, ascending: true });

  
  // Filter column 15 for the last 3 months and next 3 months
  var today = new Date();
  var threeMonthsAgo = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 3, today.getDate());
  var threeMonthsFromNow = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 3, today.getDate());
  
  // Set new filter criteria for column 15
  var criteriaColumn15 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .setHiddenValues(
      sheet.getDataRange().getValues().map(function(row, index) {
        var dateInColumn15 = row[14]; // Assuming column 15 (0-based index)
        return (dateInColumn15 >= threeMonthsAgo && dateInColumn15 <= threeMonthsFromNow) ? null : index + 2;
      }).filter(function(row) { return row !== null; }) // Remove null values
    ).build();

  sheet.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(15);
  sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(15, criteriaColumn15);

  // Filter out entries in column 5 with " Minor W"
  sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextDoesNotContain('Minor W').build());
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your problem #1, setHiddenValues method is used to hide specific values, not a range of values. To filter column 6 from values 2500 to 2599, you need to get all unique values in the column,

```
  var column6Values = sheet.getRange(2, 6, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues().flat();
  var hiddenValuesColumn6 = column6Values.filter(function(value) {
    return value < 2500 || value > 2599;
  });
  sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(6, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(hiddenValuesColumn6).build());
```

you can also try using whenNumberBetween() to filter out the ones that are not in the range 2500-2599, and then use setHiddenValues with this filtered list.

```
sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(6, SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenNumberBetween(2500, 2599).build());
```

Other issues are similar to the one above. You’re trying to hide rows based on a condition (date being within the last 3 months and next 3 months), but setHiddenValues doesn’t support conditions. You need to get all unique dates in the column, filter out the ones that are not within the desired date range, and then use setHiddenValues with this filtered list.